# How to upgrade to WDDM 1.1 on Intel-R--82945G-Express-Chipset-Family--Microsoft-Corporation

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-phone, chipset

My desktop PC has an `Intel-R--82945G-Express-Chipset-Family--Microsoft-Corporation` with WDDM 1.0 I. I need to upgrade it to WDDM 1.1 for Windows phone 7 emulator to work.

With the present WDDM 1.0, I am not able to access internet in Windows Phone 7 emulator.

I want to know whether it is feasible or not to upgrade to WDDM 1.1

Comment: Feasible or possible?

Answer (score 4):

What it's asking for is that you have a video driver that is WDDM 1.1 compliant.

Unfortunately no such thing exists as the 82945G chipset family is now a legacy product.

You'll need to get a (modern, but not necessarily fast or expensive) dedicated graphics card to use the emulator, so for that you'll need an available PCI-Express slot.